# How do external js work?? From what I've read this should work why doesn't it?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a very simple problem understanding the scope of variables with external javascript pages.  From what I read if I call an external sheet all global functions and variables should be able to be accessed.  I can't seem to get it to work.  Knowing the right question to ask to search is the hard part and I could comb through the internet for days for a problem someone could probably explain easily and quickly.  I have seen something simliar in this tutorial http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptexternal.php,  I searched quickly stack found this: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) and even as I write this I'm looking for the answer.

Simply I have an external sheet in the same directory and the file name is trial.js. Then I have an index.html simply trying to use the global function from the external trial.js to the index page.  This is possible? according to the tizag tutorial using a function in the button onclick attribute.  Also many frameworks work on this principle too right?  Although I know they are a bit more sophisticated using $(a)<~~~references?? or something.  Thanks for anyone's help I'll continue to look but hopefully the internet can help!!

localhost/trial.js:

```
function trySomething(){
    alert("trying");
}
```

localhost/index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Objects222</title>
<script src="trial.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        trySomething();
    </script>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

It was originally in resource but I wanted to make it even simplier.  using firefox and chrome doesn't work for me???  Those who say it's working upon loading the page you get an alert that says "trying" ?  Anyone any ideas why it might not be working locally.  I cleared all my cache and tried renaming to force upload.  Also used Chrome, Firefox, and IE still no alert on load @ localhost.

Comment: your script source tag is pointing to resource/trial.js, but according to your question, it's located at localhost/trial.js? Is this just a typo?

Comment: Check in the network panel of your browser's developer tools whether the file is correctly loaded. If so, it should work.

Comment: No, `$(a)` is no special thing. The `$` is just a global variable with an (odd?) short name, and its value is a function. You could do `$ = trySomething;` and then call `$()` as well.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your example. As per the tutorial, global function is accessible to any script that calls it (albeit the tutorial page uses it in an `onclick` attribute, which is no longer such a popular technique).

Comment: Sorry about the /resource/ I meant to make it as simple as possible for the question.  I fixed it but still not getting the alert on page load now tried Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I don't think your supposed to have a / before "Resources". ex. "Resources/myscript" would work. Also, if "trial.js" is in the same directory as "index.html" then you don't need "Resources/".

Comment: the `/` is valid, especially if the script is located at localhost/resource/trial.js; it's just whether or not it's correct for solving this problem.

Comment: `'Resources'` is not the same as `'resources'` in most usual cases. Even more obviously, `'resource'` is not the same as `'resources'`.

Comment: typo on my part I was brought it down to the same folder and checked my call I made the edit's on the page still not working locally but seems to work fine in a published environment.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on Apache and it works fine, **assuming that your external JavaScript file is located within a folder called resource.**

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should be fine so I copied your code and [tested it](http://dev.orangedigital.com.au/test/stack/) and it is working for me. The one change I made was to remove the first slash in the script src because my "resource" folder isn't in the site root. Is your js file definitely being loaded?

Comment: It does work here in this test/stack that is awesome.  Any ideas why it might not be working locally?

Comment: I have cleared my javascript history as well as renamed the file to trial1.js and made the necessary changes to the <script src="trial1.js">  still not working in localhost ... just wanted to add so that maybe someone can help hunt the problem down with me.

Comment: now suddenly working something kicked in.  But had you not shown me that it works by offering it in a published stage I would not have forced it through.  Seems I will have to become accustomed to no breakpoints and Stack errors to save me... which is daunting.  Can't vote or I'd +1 this. THANK YOU!